# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error when posting multipart form data(text and files) to an external api in java

Tags: java

Here we need to post multipart body with text parameters and files to an external api to upload the files so we tried with below code, but its giving java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error when calling the httpclient.execute method. can anyone pls give any inputs to resolve this.
Thanks in advance

```
 HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(uri);
   
      MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
      builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
          for (NameValuePair param : body) {            
               builder.addTextBody(param.getName(), param.getValue(), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
          }
    if (files != null && !files.isEmpty()) {
        for (File file : files) {
               byte[] arr = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getPath()));
               builder.addBinaryBody(
                    "files",
                    arr,
                    ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                    file.getName()
            );
        }
    }
    HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);
    postRequest.addHeader("Authorization", authorization);       
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

below is the exception stacktrace

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:879)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:122)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.writeTo(ByteArrayBody.java:97)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:134)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:157)
at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:113)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
```

and I am using a mock(https://run.mocky.io/v3/d734cbfc-4d78-4654-8f0b-c00bd5912fbd) as an external api for development and I am trying to upload 2 files which are one pdf and one jpeg format and both are less than 200kb

Comment: Hi There, please post your stack trace exception. Without an executable code, no information what is the external service (therefore no way of verifying if you are following their documentation) and no log error your question is close to impossible to answer. And please mask any confidential information for whatever you post :)

Comment: The peer seems to have closed the connection while you are still writing it. You are probably exceeding an upload limit at the server.